# Rank values in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting, stored-procedures, sql-order-by, mysql-8.0

I am having trouble finding a solution. I need to make a column that rank from the most to the least value **(column bedrag)**. If the values are the same then the value with the highest number **( column spelersnr )** 'wins'.
I hope you can help me out.

This is what I got so far.

```
SELECT    s.spelersnr, 
          naam , 
          (select max(bedrag) from boetes b  where b.spelersnr = s.spelersnr) as mbedrag,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS POSITIE
FROM      spelers s, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  mbedrag ;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8+ or later?  Implementing `RANK` using session variables can be a real pain in MySQL.

Comment: Yes I am using MySQL 8+.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank

Comment: Thank you I will check that out and educate myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are using MySQL 8+, you may try using the `ROW_NUMBER` function here.  Also, we can rewrite your query using a join, to eliminate the correlated subquery in the select clause:

```
SELECT s.spelersnr, s.naam,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.mbedrag DESC, s.spelersnr DESC) rn
FROM spelers s
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT spelersnr, MAX(bedrag) AS mbedrag
    FROM boetes
    GROUP BY spelersnr
) b
    ON s.spelersnr = b.spelersnr
ORDER BY
    b.mbedrag;
```

Comment: I would do a `LEFT JOIN`... just in case.

Comment: Great i didn't know the function **ROW_NUMBER()**. Thanks for your solution and time.

Comment: @TheImpaler I generally agree with you, except that the OP would need to clarify how the sorting should happen in case there is no max `bedrag` value found.  I guess what I wrote above was enough for the OP in this case.